# Plotting Spheres with dots

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to create the four images as shown here. The third one I tried and the code is.

```
unitSphere = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]},
             {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 1,
             PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0]], Mesh -> {11, 0},
             MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]

rad = 0.4; 
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{rad*Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], rad*Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], rad*Cos[θ]}, 
       {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π},ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &)]

Show[unitSphere, plot]
```

How can I get all the four with the outer sphere as dotted curves as shown in the figure?

Comment: One way is to use `MeshStyle -> {{Thickness[0.005], Dashing[0.005]}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you pretty close, although you might want to play about a little with some of the parameters.

First, your `unitSphere` can easily be adapted to produce the points in the plot by

```
m = 14; n = 50;
unitspherepoints = Table[{Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}, 
  {θ, 0, Pi, π/m}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π, π/n}];

unitsphere = ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[unitspherepoints, 1], PlotStyle -> Purple];
```

where I've left `m` and `n` for you to tune.

One (easily generalizeable) way to go is to define a function that will make the "inner plots", given a centre and list of radii:

```
innerplot[centre_, rad_] := 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  centre + rad {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]}, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Mesh -> 25, PlotStyle -> "SunsetColors"]
```

("SunsetColors" seemed closer than "Rainbow".) You could also use `Ellipsoid` here, but you probably want the `Mesh` that comes with `ParametricPlot3D`.

Next, we can create a list of centres and radii that appears to approximate those shown in your figure:

```
cenrad = {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
          {{0, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 1}}, 
          {{0, 0, 0}, {0.3, 0.5, 0.3}}, 
          {{0, 0, 0.8}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.2}}};
```

Then `innerplot @@@ cenrad` will give you all the inner ellipsoids, but we want to add a couple of extras:

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[
  Show[unitsphere, innerplot[##], 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 3]},   
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}] & @@@ cenrad,
  2], ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

You can, of course, create your own `cenrad` lists. Just make sure that each element in the list has the form

```
{..., {{x, y, z}, {rx, ry, rz}}, ...}
```

where `{x, y, z}` is the centre and `{rx, ry, rz}` are the radii along the axes.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative way

```
spherepoint[r1_, r2_, r3_] = Table[{r1 Sin[q1] Cos[q2], r2  Sin[q1] Sin[q2], r3 Cos[q1] },
                                   {q1, 0, Pi, Pi/8}, {q2, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/40}];

n1 = 1; n2 = 2; n3 = 2;
Show[ListPointPlot3D[spherepoint[n1,n2,n3], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
                     PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]],
     Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]]
```

[image]

You can get different configuration by changing `n1,n2,n3`. You can replace `Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]` with your `unitSphere`.

You can move the sphere as well by shifting the origin. For above example, I choose `{0,0,0}`. Let's put it at `{0, 0, 3/4 n3}` with a larger radius for the points.

```
n1 = 2; n2 = 2; n3 = 4;
Show[ListPointPlot3D[spherepoint[n1, n2, n3], BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
                      PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]], 
     Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 3/4 n3}, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. How do I get the last one? I am not getting that by changing the parameters. Also, how can I get the same color as in the figure that I have posted?

Comment: You need to change the origin of the sphere. Check the new answer.